# Count a select result number

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I'm creating a interface to run a SQL query (C++ and QT), but i want to page and count the results.

Something like:

```
select count (User select) as count and select (user select) limit 100;
```

Example:

```
select count (select * from tbl_data where id >10);
```

Is there a way to do that or use the SQLITE3 library to do that?

Regards.

Comment: Far as I can see, `select count(*) from tbl_data where id >10;` is the same as your Example.  Not sure what your limit does in the "Something like".

Comment: it works, but i dont want to do a lot of manipulation in the user select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way

```
select count(*) from (select tbl_name, sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table') as data;
```

Thanks